# How to read char after char from command line parameter?

Tags: c, windows, string, command-line

I'm the very beginner in C. In my program, user is going to add an argument via command line. This argument will be a string e.g. "Hello, how are you". I would like to read char after char from this string. This string has an unknown size. So example of executing program (in Windows) is: test "Hello, how are you"

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c;  

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Character c should be read from input string, which is something I can't make.
I hope I made it clear.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` reads from the standard input, so what your program does is to read from standard input character by character, and print them to standard output. There is one mistake, you should declare `c` as an `int`, because `EOF` is usually `-1`.

---

However, you are trying to print the command line argument. To accomplish that, you don't need to do it character by character. You need to use `main` version with arguments like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

When you call the program `test "Hello, how are you"`, `argv[1]` is already the argument string `Hello, how are you`. You can use this string directly.

I won't give you the code, you can use `printf` to print string. If you like to get every single character, use a loop to get it from the string `argv[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

Command line parameters in C are passed to the main function. You must declare the main function with the following signature:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Then `argc` is the number of command line parameters, `argv` is an array of strings containing each parameter.

You can then access each character with a simple loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; i++) {
    char c = argv[1][i];
    // Use c as you need
}
```